# How to call a repository and fetch results in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-types

I have a simple call to fetch results by fetching results from a table. Everytime I end up getting

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)

Not sure what am doing wrong

Here is my code

Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(path = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<PricingRuleEntity> getRoRLogEmailzamphia() {
        return reportService.getRoRLogEmail();
    }
```

Service

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ReportService {
    private final PricingRuleRepository pricingRuleRepository;
    
    public List<PricingRuleEntity> getRoRLogEmail() {
        List<PricingRuleEntity> list;
        list = pricingRuleRepository.findByActiveAndValidUptoIsBefore(true, LocalDate.now());
        return list;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PricingRuleRepository extends JpaRepository<PricingRuleEntity, UUID> {
    List<PricingRuleEntity> findByActiveAndValidUptoIsBefore(boolean active, LocalDate now);

}
```

Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "pricing_rule")
public class PricingRuleEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name="applicable_for")
    private String applicableFor;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="applicable_for_app")
    private String applicableForApp;

    @Column(name = "doc_status", nullable = false)
    private Integer docStatus;

    @Column(name = "creation")
    private String creation;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "disable", nullable = false)
    private Integer disable;

    @Column(name = "apply_on", nullable = false)
    private String applyOn;

    @Column(name = "price_or_product_discount", nullable = false)
    private String priceOrProductDiscount;

    @Column(name = "territory", nullable = false)
    private String territory;

    @Column(name = "min_qty")
    private Double minQty;

    @Column(name = "max_qty")
    private Double maxQty;

    @Column(name = "min_amt")
    private Double minAmt;

    @Column(name = "max_amt")
    private Double maxAmt;

    @Column(name = "valid_from", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate validFrom;

    @Column(name = "valid_upto", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate validUpto;

    @Column(name = "margin_type")
    private String marginType;

    @Column(name = "discount_amount")
    private Double discountAmount;

    @Column(name = "discount_percentage")
    private Double discountPercentage;

    @Column(name = "rule_description")
    private String ruleDescription;

    @Column(name = "promotional_scheme")
    private String promotionalScheme;

    @Column(name = "campaign", nullable = true)
    private String campaign;

    @Column(name = "promotion_image_url")
    private String promotionImageUrl;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "JSON")
    public List<PromoItem> items;
}
```

The null pointer is thrown on this line

```
   list = pricingRuleRepository.findByActiveAndValidUptoIsBefore(true, LocalDate.now());
```

The Error log

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JsonTypeDescriptor.fromString(JsonTypeDescriptor.java:104)
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JsonTypeDescriptor.wrap(JsonTypeDescriptor.java:165)
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.AbstractJsonSqlTypeDescriptor$1.doExtract(AbstractJsonSqlTypeDescriptor.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2775)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1735)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1661)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1550)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:734)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:979)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2609)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2592)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2419)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1450)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1402)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1374)
    at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.findByActiveAndValidUptoIsBefore(Unknown Source)
    at com.blackbird.falcon.service.ReportService.getRoRLogEmail(ReportService.java:25)
    at com.blackbird.falcon.service.ReportService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e95617ee.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.blackbird.falcon.service.ReportService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$678591cb.getRoRLogEmail(<generated>)
    at com.blackbird.falcon.controller.DataController.getRoRLogEmailzamphia(DataController.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I am totally lost, not sure why am getting a `NullPointerException` and I am passing the correct values. The query generated by hibernate,  I can run it on the Database side and get the results, with the hard coded values passed. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please add more of the NPE stacktrace so we know at which location of your code the NPE is thrown.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I have added where the nullpointer is being thrown

Comment: Your problem is probably not related to spring boot but how your json column is mapped in hibernate and what data is being stored in the row you are trying to fetch. Attach a debugger and see why the null is passed in there.

Comment: try @JsonProperty